# Kubernetes Role should grant access to all resources but it ignores some resources

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

The role `namespace-limited` should have full access to all resources (of the specified API groups) inside of a namespace. My Role manifest looks like this:

```
kind: Role
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: namespace-limited
  namespace: restricted-xample
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - core
  - apps
  - batch
  - networking.k8s.io
  resources: ["*"] # asterisk to grant access to all resources of the specified api groups
  verbs: ["*"]
```

I associated the Role to a ServiceAccount using a RoleBinding but unfortunately this ServiceAccount has no access to `Pod`, `Service`, `Secret`, `ConfigMap` and `Endpoint` Resources. These resources are all part of the `core` API group. All the other common Workloads work though. Why is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The core group, also referred to as the legacy group, is at the REST path `/api/v1` and uses `apiVersion: v1`

You need to use `""` for core API group.

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  namespace: restricted-xample
  name: namespace-limited
rules:
- apiGroups: ["", "apps", "batch", "networking.k8s.io"] # "" indicates the core API group
  resources: ["*"]
  verbs: ["*"]
```

To test the permission of the service account use below commands

```
kubectl auth can-i get pods --as=system:serviceaccount:restricted-xample:default -n restricted-xample 
kubectl auth can-i get secrets --as=system:serviceaccount:restricted-xample:default -n restricted-xample 
kubectl auth can-i get configmaps --as=system:serviceaccount:restricted-xample:default -n restricted-xample
kubectl auth can-i get endpoints --as=system:serviceaccount:restricted-xample:default -n restricted-xample
```

Comment: Oh yea, I also just figured this out, but why doesn't it work if i specify the core group explicitly?

Comment: Because it's the legacy and first api and the code still follows it to not break the API

Answer (score 0):

Just figured out, that it works when I omit the core keyword, like in [this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#role-example) example. Following Role manifest works:

```
kind: Role
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: namespace-limited
  namespace: restricted-xample
rules:
- apiGroups: ["", "apps", "batch", "networking.k8s.io"]
  resources: ["*"]
  verbs: ["*"]
```

But why it does not work if I specify the `core` API group is a mystery to me.